# How to query type (int?) for any matches of type IQueryable<int>?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an `IQueryable<int>` set of data that I am using as my "match". I want to find any "Source" were the UnitID matches any of the "Units" (any of the integers).

In the following example, units is of type `IQueryable` of integers and `UnitID` being `<int?>`.

I have tried the following:

```
var units = db.Units
    .Where(x =>
        x.ModelNum.Contains(obj.ModelSerialSearch)
        || x.SerialNum.Contains(obj.ModelSerialSearch)
    )
    .Select(x => x.id);

var source = source.Where(x => x.UnitID.Contains(units));
```

I have also tried:

```
var source = source.Where(x => units.Contains(x.UnitID));
```

and

```
var source = source.Where(x => x.UnitID.ToString().Contains(units.ToString()))
```

I get the following error with my first example:

[image]

Comment: The `.Where(x => units.Contains(x.UnitID))` version seems to be on the right track. What error do you get for that?

Comment: Another approach worth a try is `var source = units.SelectMany(unit => source.Where(x => x.UnitID == unit));`

Comment: For the first I get the following exception: 
'IQueryable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<int?>(ParallelQuery<int?>, int?)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int?>

Comment: For the second (units.SelectMany) I get this exception. "System.InvalidOperationException: 'A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression.'"

Comment: Materialize the query execution for `units` by adding `.ToList()` at the end (`var units = db.Units.Where(...).Select(...).ToList();`). Meanwhile what is `source`? Is it also `IQueryable` that you try to grab the DB data via `DbContext`? If yes, I believe that it is possible to combine both queries into one to perform the query in DB side.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `source` to define `source`:

```
var source = source.Where(x => units.Contains(x.UnitID));
```

Because `source` has no type, the compiler does it's best and falls back on `int?` as the inferred type. Honestly the compiler should be complaining that `source` is undefined, but it's doing a lot of complex things so no surprise it gets that wrong.

Without a reference to your data source I'm going to make the assumption that there is a `Source` table alongside the `Unit` table. In that case the query would look like this:

```
var result = db.Source.Where(x => units.Any(y => y == x.UnitID)
```

With the definition of `units` as a separate `IQueryable<int>`, this results in a query definition that can be executed directly on the server. If you were to materialize the query as Yong Shun suggested all subsequent queries could result in entire tables being pulled out and processed by your program instead of letting the SQL server doing what it does best.

A more succinct version might be:

```
var result = db.Source.Where
    (
        s => db.Units.Any
        (
            x => x.ModelNum.Contains(obj.ModelSerialSearch)
              || x.SerialNum.Contains(obj.ModelSerialSearch)
        )
    );
```

This translates into something like the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @ModelSerialSearch NVARCHAR(5) = '%123%';

SELECT s.*   -- actually list of result fields
FROM Source s
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Units x 
    WHERE x.ModelNum LIKE @ModelSerialSearch 
        OR x.SerialNum LIKE @ModelSerialSearch
)
```

This is quite a bit more efficient than grabbing whole tables and processing the records locally.